# Why I can't get the teamviewer id?

Tags: teamviewer

I installed teamviewer via command line and I have set the passwd, when I want to get the id to connect it, there is no id

```
root@gpms:[/root/MyCode]teamviewer --info

 TeamViewer                           12.0.76279  (RPM)

 teamviewerd status                   ● teamviewerd.service - TeamViewer remote control daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/teamviewerd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-04-24 13:29:37 HKT; 15s ago
  Process: 1740 ExecStart=/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/teamviewerd -d (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3265 (teamviewerd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/teamviewerd.service
           └─3265 /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/teamviewerd -d

Apr 24 13:29:32 gpms systemd[1]: Starting TeamViewer remote control daemon...
Apr 24 13:29:36 gpms systemd[1]: PID file /var/run/teamviewerd.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
Apr 24 13:29:37 gpms systemd[1]: Started TeamViewer remote control daemon.

 TeamViewer ID:
Try restarting the TeamViewer daemon (e.g. teamviewer --daemon restart)
```

and the teamviewerd.pid is readable

```
root@gpms:[/root/MyCode]ls -l  /var/run/teamviewerd.pid
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4 Apr 24 13:29 /var/run/teamviewerd.pid
```

OS: CentOS 7

How can I get the ID?

Comment: The PID file message is purely informational. As you can see, the daemon process’ status is correctly reported.

Answer (score 0):

Teamviewer doesn't generate ID when you lack Internet connectivity. Since you don't mention it, I guess you have Internet connectivity. My guess is that something else is blocking teamviewer to connect to the Internet - less likely - firewall, and more likely - SElinux.

There are some nice articles on how to configure SElinux to alloow Teamviewer to work properly, e.g. [this one](https://medium.com/@parijathakumar/teamviewer-and-selinux-on-fedora-24-344e71c3816a) (it's for Fedora, but it should work on CentOS too).